# Why is producer in pykafka so slow?

Tags: python, kafka-producer-api, pykafka

I wrote a simple producer using pykafka but can't seem to get it to perform.  The basic producer and call to produce is below.  When I call this 100 times with a small message, and add some timing/profiling code, it takes about 14 seconds.  I understand this to be an asynchronous sending of messages so I would expect it to be incredibly fast.  Is there some setting I'm missing?  I've also tried it with min_queued_messages=1 and those takes about 2 seconds longer.

```
from pykafka import KafkaClient
import time

client = KafkaClient(hosts="kafka1.mydomain.com:9092", exclude_internal_topics=False)
topic = client.topics['mytopic']

start = time.time()

for x in xrange(100):
    with topic.get_producer(delivery_reports=False,
                            sync=True,
                            linger_ms=0) as producer:
        producer.produce("This is a message")

end = time.time()
print "Execution Time (ms): %s" % round((end - start) * 1000)
```

I did do a profile of this within pycharm and is says hat 78.8% of the time is spent on "time.sleep"?!  Why would it be sleeping?

Comment: I am not sure this will help, but _[this link](https://github.com/Parsely/pykafka/issues/334)_ is discussing differences between `pykafka` and `kafka-python`, and their different handling of creating topics dynamically.

Comment: Looks like if I set "required_acks=0" then my run time drops to about 1500 ms!

Answer (score 2):

The `topic.get_producer` call is meant to be called once at the beginning of the producer's lifespan. Calling it in a tight loop as your example code does will cause the initialization sequence to be run repeatedly, which is unnecessary and will add a lot of overhead. Your code would work faster if it were changed to the following:

```
with topic.get_producer(delivery_reports=False,
                        sync=True,
                        linger_ms=0) as producer:
    for x in xrange(100):
        producer.produce("This is a message")
```